# How can I install R mockery package using conda?

Tags: r, conda, mockery

I want to install this package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mockery/README.html

I'm trying to install it in my conda environment but `conda install -c r r-mockery` yields an error saying that the package could not be found.

Is there a reason why some packages on CRAN could be uninstallable via conda?

Answer (score 0):

It could be version Issue. Please post some details regarding what version of R you are using and see if the package is available for that version of R.